# Repair Bad Json with Unescaped Quote in Field Name

Tags: json, parsing, kissmetrics

Kissmetrics exports apparently produce invalid json when there is a quote in the field name, for example, the following is one of the events produced:

```
{
    "ab test group  native dialogs on mobile":"Control",
    "ab test group  "interested" button copy":"Interested",
    "_t":1412633724,
    "_p":"hk5yxuxcqe/935mkbj+pz8xi0a8="
}
```

(Newlines were added to clarify the issue, we can't use those to repair the JSON).

I am looking for a mechanism for repairing such broken JSON.

There are som assumptions I believe we can take advantage of:

- We can assume that the JSON being produced is flat (no nested objects or arrays), so I think we can take advantage of that.
- I believe all fields are strings, except for _t, but not 100% sure.
- I don't think we can assume the bad unescaped quotes will be balanced.
- I believe KM removes commas and colons from field names, but not 100% sure -- they are not removed from values (though I believe values to be properly encoded).

Comment: This is a tough problem, because it's ambiguous - it's hard to tell if interested is a new property or should be escaped in the property name. I would think about a regular expression that will identify lines (e.g. " which is neither followed by a : nor preceded by a , with optional whitespace). That is not perfect, but if these are all property names, you can start generating some regular expressions to fix the strings. I would recommend try that out, running your import and export anything that fails to parse after and iterate on the regular expressions, for a quick fix.

Comment: For this particular problem, it turns out KM provides a script to fix their bad JSON: https://gist.github.com/clay-whitley/8309396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I am using now, in python, which I'm sure is imperfect:

```
match = regex.match(r'^{("(?P<fieldName>([^:]*))":(?P<fieldValue>([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)|("(([^"])|(\\"))*"))(,|}))*$', s)

fieldNames = match.captures('fieldName')
fieldValues = match.captures('fieldValue')

newJson = "{%s}" % (
    ",".join(
        "\"%s\":%s" % (
            fieldName.replace("\"", "\\\""),
            fieldValue,
        )
        for fieldName, fieldValue
        in zip(fieldNames, fieldValues)        
    )
)
```

This assumes there are no colons in the keys.